# ASP.NET MVC date format mm/dd/yyyy at 00:00 (EST)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to print date time format in MVC like.

```
@{
   var d= Datetime.Today;
}
@d
```

Output: `07/18/2013 2:26 PM`

But I need to print like: `07/18/2013 at 2:26 PM`

Comment: no i used rocket science

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
@{
   string d = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy 'at' h:mm tt");
 }
@d
```

Comment: Works fine when I tested it

Comment: I changed HH to h, otherwise it will display 14:26 PM instead of 2:26 PM.